# I have a problem in dll?

Tags: database, delphi, ide, activex

I create a form inside the Dll. But it compile is not successfully.Some Error below.

" Access violation at address 004EB784 in module 'Project1dll.dll'.Read of address 00000048"

Thanks.....

Comment: I think you mean address 004EB785.

Comment: That's a run-time error, not a compile time error.  You need to debug your code to find out what the problem is.

Comment: `@Adamski`: that would be too easy with `004EB785`. You try to solve it for `004EB784`

Comment: Please at least show us the code around where the exception is thrown.

Comment: And why have you tagged it database and activex? Are those little hints? Maybe you could provide more detail in your question?

Comment: I must be missing something.  What's with the 84/85 thing in the addresses?

Comment: Mason, you're too young to know that 004EB784 is the hardware register for magic smoke: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke

Comment: Mason, they're just being wise-asses by latching onto the address that Tobassum gave as though it were a meaningful part of the question. They're not even *trying* to be helpful, so go ahead and flag their comments as noise, like I did.

Answer (score 2):

You are dereferencing a nil pointer somehow.  Perhaps an object that hasn't been created?

Answer (score 0):

As well you should have a look here, it might help if your trouble is elsewhere ..
[Forms in dll](http://www.link-rank.com/dll.htm)

Answer (score 0):

here's something i've found necessary to do this.  see my example function below:

```
procedure DoSomething(hApp:THandle); export;
var
  hDllApplication:THandle;
begin
  hDllApplication:=Application.Handle;
  Application.Handle:=hApp;
  try
    DoItNow;
  finally
    Application.Handle:=hDllApplication;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: if you have database code in your DLL, you must do the same with Session.